# Intern on IOS - Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild failure: not found: carthage

Tags: ios, appium, appium-ios, intern, carthage

When I am running Intern Standalone 
staring appium and then Running Intern Script Script perfectly works

By when I Run same using java Program at that time it gives issue

UnknownError: [POST http://localhost:65505/wd/hub/session / {"desiredCapabilities":{"name":"DS/tests/intern.js","idle-timeout":60,"platformName":"iOS","deviceName":"iPhone 6","bundleId":"com.apple.mobilesafari","automationName":"XCUITest","Simulator":true}}] An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild failure: not found: carthage
 at Server.createSession

Carthage is installed correctly 
Is there any access issue to it

Please please help

Comment: Is carthage in your path? Does reinstalling carthage help? (See https://github.com/facebookarchive/WebDriverAgent/issues/840#issuecomment-495592509)

Comment: Added Carthage path to PATH (:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin/carthage) since the same issue . I have installed appium by npm install appium@1.15.1   so there is no .app file  ( /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app: No such file or directory_

Answer (score 0):

***Problem with Carthage Folder, Check in below path*** /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium-webdriveragent
[Carthage Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdr99.png)
If it is not there, Follow Below steps

**Step-1**: For Appium 1.15.1 and above

- Open below path in Terminal

$ cd /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules

$ sudo chmod -R 777 . appium-webdriveragent/*

**Step-2**: goto
1) $ cd /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-webdriveragent

2) sudo mkdir -p Resources/WebDriverAgent.bundle

3) sudo sh ./Scripts/bootstrap.sh -d

**Step-3**: **Build WebDriverAgent Project with sign**

Open below project in XCode 
/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium-webdriveragent/WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj